# Extending a structure

Tags: c, struct

```
typedef struct A 
{
  int x;
}A;

typedef struct B 
{
  A a;
  int d;
}B;

void fn()
{
  B *b;
  ((A*)b)->x = 10;
}
```

I read the above code snippet in SO. `((A*)b)->x`is not good programming style.`b->a.x` is good programming style. Because anybody adds something before the statement "A a;" in structure b , it will not work. I don't understand why? I tried it too. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Why would `b` be casted to `A*`? The two types are seemingly unrelated, except for `B` having a member of type `A`. To my understanding, the assignment `((A*)b)->x = 10` would depend on specific memory layout.

Comment: b->a.x is easy to understand. But the other format is not easy to understand for me.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the two assignments do different things structurally in the first place, and have the same result at best by chance.

Comment: Yeah, Both assignments does the same thing. My doubt is why the statement A a; should be first statement of structure b to get the desired result with `((A*)b)->x`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That trick is used to emulate inheritance in C. It makes possible to pass address A or B to function which expects pointer to A.

This works because C guarantees that there is no padding before the first member of struct. So if A is first member of B, memory layout at the beginning of B is always same as A.

```
int doStuff(A * a) {
    return a->x + 1;
}

...

B b;
doStuff((A*)&b); // Will work because b and b.a have the same start address
```

If you would change B declaration:

```
typedef struct B 
{
    int d;
    A a;
}B;
```

this would no longer work as `(A*)&b` would return address of `b.d`, not `b.a`.

Comment: Quite interesting, I was totally unaware of this possibility to implement inheritance in C. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Word of warning though: This is still a trick, and it easily gets hard to maintain. I really recommend using language which supports inheritance as a core feature, if possible.

Comment: The case described here (and asked by the OP) is less interesting though because (as the OP stated) B carries knowledge about containing an A, so indeed b.a.x is the immediately possible and proper way to go. By contrast, handling A* s which point to Bs and accessing B's member d is the interesting use case. It requires the same disciplin with respect to member ordering when declaring "derived" structs that was asked about by the OP.

Comment: Careful with multiple inheritance. Obviously, only the first superclass is correctly aligned; additional superclasses take some more effort. Upcast is easy; like Peter said, use `b->a` instead of `(A*)b`. For a downcast, you will have to do some pointer arithmetics: `static B dummyB;` `#define B_OFFSET_A ((char *)&dummyB.a - (char *)&dummyB)` `#define DOWNCAST(a) ((B *)((char *)(a) - B_OFFSET_A))`

Comment: In my case , ((A*)b) ll give the address of first element of structure A. So we can access x. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Ruud Things will certainly get interesting with C and multiple inheritance. Only advice I would give is: *Don't do it.*

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is a "poor man's inheritance". Like true inheritance in C++ it's used to define a type which comprises the common features (data, function pointers) of objects which may in fact carry more information than just that common subset.

That technique is widely used in e.g. GhostScript where printer drivers carry some common information and on top special information to control that particular printer model.

The C language mechanism employed here is that a struct is essentially the concatenation of its data in memory, **in the order of member declaration.** That order is important for getting access right after casting. 
The memory layout of your B is `|---int x---|---int d ---|`. There is no additional information stored. An `A *` points to the first element, x; so does a `B *`. You could have a struct c

```
struct C 
{
   B b; 
   float f; 
};
```

whose layout would be `|---int x---|---int d ---|-----float f---|`. The interesting thing is that you can pass an `A *pa` to a function which somehow knows that pa actually points to a C and cast that "down": `((C *)pa)->f`. `(C *)pa` does not change the value of pa but just tells the compiler what it points to (at the responsibility of the programmer). The knowledge about what type *actually* is hidden in the object is often encoded in an enum/int data member which is manually set to a magic, type-indicating value when the object is created.

Comment: Just nitpicking: `(C *)pa` is called a downcast, not an upcast. See: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148615/what-is-upcasting-downcasting

Comment: One more doubt. Does the statement A a; in structure b convert into structure A's members?

Comment: @user3168736 It does, in the sense that the memory contains nothing than the data of A's members. In particular the memory doesn't contain anything that would identify it as belonging to an A -- that information is only available at compile time from the declarations. At compile time the compiler will enforce that access to a's members happens only through a, i.e. you must write b.a.x and cannot write b.x (except for anonymous structs: `struct O { struct { int ii; }; } o; int i = o.ii;`, but I fail to see the benefit of that, except for generated code).